# EDI X12 - 204 and 404 speciciation

Tags: edi, x12

I need to generate EDI X12 document (V4010) for 204 and 404 format.
Where can i find the specification for 404 and 204 formats.

Comment: I am usually the following site, it's quite good ;-) http://www.faima.com/edi_4010/ts204.htm http://www.faima.com/edi_4010/ts404.htm

Answer (score 0):

Most of them now, you *should* find at the X12 store http://store.x12.org/store/.
For several, you can sort of put together some meaningful information from other people's guides.
Example:
http://www.loweslink.com/pubdocuments/204v4010.pdf